# Wait/reconnect until TCP client connection can be established?

Tags: node.js

Here is an example of how to create a TCP client connection from the node net docs (https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_connect_options_connectlistener)

```
const client = net.createConnection({ port: 1905 }, () => {
    // 'connect' listener
    console.log('connected to server!');
    client.write('world!\r\n');
});
client.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
    client.end();
});
client.on('end', () => {
    console.log('disconnected from server');
});
```

If the server is not available I get `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1905`.

What would be a good way to wait/reconnect until the server is available and connect when it is, instead of throwing an error?

EDIT: Here is an alternative approach I have tried, but here I get the problem

> MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak
>   detected. 11 connect listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to
>   increase limit

I would like the latest listener to replace earlier listeners. They all listen for the same thing. I just want to retry.

```
function initTcpClient() {
    console.log("Initiating TCP client...")
    var tcpSocket = new net.Socket();
    const client = net.createConnection({ port: 1905 }, () => {

    tcpSocket.on('error', function onError(err) {
        setTimeout(connect, 1000);
    });

    connect();

    function connect() {
        console.log("Looking for TCP server...");
        tcpSocket.connect(argv.tcpport, argv.tcphost, function onConnected() {
            console.log("Connecting to TCP server...");
            tcpSocket.on('data', function onIncoming(data) {
                if (connectedWebsocketClient) {
                    console.log('Forwarding to WebSocket: %s', data);
                    webSocketClient.send(data.toString());
                } else {
                    console.log('Not connected to websocket client. Dropping incoming TCP message: %s', data);
                }
            });
            tcpSocket.on('close', function onClose(hadError) {
                console.log("Connection to TCP server was closed.");
                connectedToTcpServer = false;
                setTimeout(connect, 1000);
            });
            console.log("Connected to TCP server.");
            connectedToTcpServer = true;
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: You could add `client.on("error")` to catch the event. Then in the callback check if it is a result of ECONNREFUSED then with a setTimeout try to connect again. You may also want to look at `net.connect()` and use named callbacks instead of arrow funcs as it will make that reconnection logic easier to reason about

Comment: @Alex You put your answer into a comment, did you know that?

Comment: If I remember correctly I was not able to do that since the error occured before the callback passed to createConnection, containing the on error handler, was invoked.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I will add it as an answer now. I was on a phone and did not realize it.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Feel free to see my edit also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here to elaborate on my comment. Is an example that will work. Try it with a simple tcp server. Start the client and then after a few seconds start the server. It is important to register you listeners after a reconnect happens in `onError` You may also want to have a limit of how many times you want to try to reconnect.

```
const net = require('net')

let client = connect()
client.on('data', onData);
client.on('error', onError);
client.on("close", onClose);


function onData(data) {
    console.log(data)
}

function onError(err) {
    if(err.message.indexOf('ECONNREFUSED') > -1) {
        //do recconect
        console.log("Attempting to reconnect shortly")
        setTimeout(()=>{
            client = connect();
            client.on('data', onData);
            client.on('error', onError);
            client.on("close", onClose);

        },1000)
    }
}
 function onClose() {
    console.log("Removng all listeners")
    client.removeAllListeners("data");
    client.removeAllListeners("error")
}




function connect() {
    const c = net.createConnection({
        port: 3000
   },
    ()=>{
        console.log('connected')
    });

    return c
}
```